# Login URL does not redirect, when the user is logged in successfully in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect the user to their Profile page when they have logged into their account, the redirect is not working and I do not get any errors in the terminal. I am using the latest version of Django.

main urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from django.contrib import admin
from authentication import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^authentication/', include('authentication.urls')),
    url(r'^emails/', include('emails.urls')),
    url(r'^profiles/', include('profiles.urls',namespace='profiles')),
```

]

profiles urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from profiles import views

app_name='profiles'
urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^profile/(?P<user_id>\d+)/$', views.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
]
```

profiles view

```
def user_profile(request,user_id):
    return render(request,'profiles/detail/profile.html')
```

login view in authentication module

```
 def Login(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    regForm = SignUpForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = LoginForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['login_username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['login_password']
            user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse('profiles:user_profile',request.user.id))
            else:
                return render(request, 'index.html',{'error':'The username and password didnt match','form':form,'regForm':regForm})
        else:
            print 'form is not valid'
    else:
         return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form,'regForm':regForm})
```

error

> The`enter code here` included URLconf '2' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Comment: try `return redirect(reverse()))`

Comment: Show the full login view.

Comment: iv posted it my full login code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the actual login form template I didn't have an action in the form tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.urls import reverse
if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profiles:user_profile',args=(request.user.id,)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, if doesn't work or you don't understand tell me

```
def Login(request):
    form = LoginForm()
    regForm = SignUpForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = LoginForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['login_username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['login_password']
            user = authenticate(request,username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect(reverse('profiles:user_profile',request.user.id))
            else:
                return render(request, 'index.html',{'error':'The username and password didnt match','form':form,'regForm':regForm})
        else:
            print 'form is not valid'
    else:
         if request.user.is_authenticated():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('success_url_here')
         else:
           return render(request, 'index.html','form':form,'regForm':regForm})
```

Comment: it does redirect but I get an error which I have posted above

Comment: I think the error is in de user_profuke view, the parameter user_id is not being use, delete or give a use